# Excel Macro Expected Function or variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am following this script

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3921-excel-save-and-close-workbook-after-inactivity.html

it looks simple and straight forward.

but when I open the excel file I get these errors

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Compile error:

Expected Function or variable
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong

but everything looks alright to me

[image]

any idea how to fix that?

Thanks K Daves

Do you know why I get error on End Sub and On Error Resume Next?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an HTML coding error on their website.

In the sub `TimeSetting()`, it should look like this:

```
Sub TimeSetting()
    CloseTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
      Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

The `<span style="background-color:#ff0">` portion that was in your code was actually meant to style the the Sub on their website - not meant to be part of the code.

Comment: I can't see the full code as it's blocked by the other window.  Update `TimeSetting` sub and then try running it and give me the error for that along with a view of that full sub.

Comment: @asmgx Hmm must be a bug. Does it give an error when you try to run it? Maybe just remove that one sub and paste it back in there might fix it.

Comment: I just re-write the script again , now it works, apparently there are invisible chars when copied the code from the website. thx heaps